# Seeking replacement for ggmap::geocode?

Tags: r, geonames, ggmap, geocoding

I've found ggmap's [geocode()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/geocode) function really useful over the years as it's got a 'fuzzy' search implemented by Google. However, I'm wondering if there are alternatives, because

- geocode() seems unreliable sometimes
- overdependence on google
- it doesn't use/support open source API solutions

I've seen the [overpass](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/overpass)  and [geonames](https://github.com/ropensci/geonames) packages.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and discovered another solution, preferably using CRAN packages such as geonames?